# Static private function with templated type as a default argument in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer, c++17

I have the following piece of C++17 code:

```
template <typename Callback = void(*)()>
struct A {
    A(Callback c = &noop) {}
private:
    static void noop() {}
};

int main() {
    A a{};
}
```

Clang 6 compiles this without any errors, but GCC 8.2 says:

```
In function ‘A(Callback)-> A<Callback> [with Callback = void (*)()]’:
3:24: error: ‘static void A<Callback>::noop() [with Callback = void (*)()]’ is private within this context
  A(Callback c = &noop) {}
                 ^~~~~
5:14: note: declared private here
  static void noop() {}
              ^~~~
```

Interestingly, if `Callback` is not a template argument but a simple type alias (i.e. if I write `using Callback = void (*)()` inside of the `A` class), both compilers are fine. Also, if instead of `A a{};` I explicitly write `A<> a{};`, both compilers are again fine. This leads me to think that this problem is somehow connected to the new C++17 class template deduction mechanism.

My question is, which of the compilers is right according to the standard? Is this a GCC bug or is Clang being too permissive?

Comment: Just a note: I had to add a template type parameter to get it to compile in the onlinegdb.com compiler; it completely ignored the default. But, it didn't throw an error otherwise.

Comment: I've added the language-lawyer tag since you're looking for an answer by the Standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CTAD notionally proceeds by synthesizing a set of functions and function templates ([[over.match.class.deduct]p1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match.class.deduct)). As relevant here, the set includes
:

> If `C` is defined, for each constructor of `C`, a function template
>   with the following properties:
>
> - The template parameters are the template parameters of `C` followed by the template parameters (including default template arguments) of
>     the constructor, if any.
> - The types of the function parameters are those of the constructor.
> - The return type is the class template specialization designated by `C` and template arguments corresponding to the template parameters of `C`.

Notably, this omits default function arguments. This is almost certainly a defect.

Unfortunately, this defect also means that nobody knows from the standard how access control works for the default function arguments of the synthesized function templates - it doesn't even permit them to exist in the first place.

---

From a design perspective, I'd expect Clang's behavior to be correct.